# Visual Studio Code for some reason changes '\' with '/' in Include Path

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, mpi, ms-mpi

So I've been trying to set up MSMPI in Visual Studio Code but fore some reason it says "Cannot find: C:/Program Files(x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include" when I'm trying to add ${MSMPI_INC} to the Include Path for C/C++. Have someone encountered this problem?
[Proof that this variable exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNAZ6.jpg)

I've tried putting the whole path not using environment variable, however it still changes the symbols and says he can't find that directory, which exists (I checked)

Comment: Isn't it `cmake` doing that, rather than VSCode?

Comment: I don't think so, because it builds using gcc, not cmake

Comment: You'll need to show your project settings (`.vscode/settings.json` ?)

Comment: fyi, Windows supports both / and \ in paths. Even both at the same time

Comment: Also it's `Program Files (x86)`, mind the space between `Files` and `(x86)`

Comment: @Raildex My God, I skipped the space -_-. Now it works, thanks!

Comment: @Raildex, can you please post it as an answer so I would mark it as solved? Or how can I do it (I've never used stack overflow)?

Comment: include should use "/" not "\". "/" in include works everywhere and "\" works only on Windows, so it is good VScode fixes this for you. Also "\" is often used as escape sequence. If your include can't find file, problem is not related to slashes, but your build configuration (includes paths are invalid or not setup correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your environment variable. It's `Program Files (x86)`. note the space between `Files` and `(x86)`.